# RxJS: Setting default value for observable from another observable

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to create observable stream which takes user id from cookie and, if not found in cookie, fetches it from API. How can I do it in RxJS?

```
var userIdRequest = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(generateIdAsync);
var cookieUserIdStream = Rx.Observable.of(getCookieValue("user_id"))
    .filter(x => x !== null);

var userIdStream = cookieUserIdStream.__ifEmptyThen__(userIdRequest()); // <<< ???

// Emulating async request for user id
// Will be a JSONp call in real app
function generateIdAsync(cb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(`id_${new Date().getTime()}`);
    }, 300);
}

function getCookieValue(name) {
    var regexp = new RegExp(`${name}=([^;]*)`);
    var match = document.cookie.match(regexp);

    return match && match[1];
}
```

There's a `defaultIfEmpty` method which works with simple values only, not with observables. In Bacon.js there's `or` method for streams, which works perfectly fine, but I don't see anything similar in RxJS. Do I miss something or do I need to implement a custom observer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may concat the 2 observables and get the first emitted value:

```
var userIdStream = Rx.Observable.concat(cookieUserIdStream, userIdRequest).first();
```

Comment: That's it, very practical ;)